# Why does the internal field names not match when working with list items using the SharePoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

When I work with list items I need to use internal field names to set the field values. I have several fields of different data types, lets focus on two: 'Comment' (Multiple lines of Text) and 'Assigned' (Person or Group). I've created both myself.

This is what I use to create/update list items, and it all works fine:
`{ "__metadata" : { "type" : "SP.Data.ListItem" }, "Comment" : "Hello", "gomsId" : 215 }`

I knew to use "Comment" and "gomsId" by getting an existing list item and looking at the format I received.

The problem is: The internal field name of 'Assigned' is `'goms'`. Not `'gomsId'`. So when I use `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/fields/getByTitle('Assigned')/internalname` to create list items it does not work.

Why is the `'Id'` part appended for this field? Is it because of the data type? How do I know which fields will have `'Id'` appended and which will not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `User` and `Lookup` field types SharePoint REST returns `lookup value part only` instead of User/Lookup field value (most likely for performance reasons). In that case the field name is generated according to the following format:  `<fieldInternalname>Id`

The new field name is introduced in order to avoid a conflict with the original name since it is still possible to return it as demonstrated below:

The following query returns `Id` property of `AssignedTo` field:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Workflow Tasks')/items?$select=AssignedToId
```

The following example returns `Id` and `Title` properties of `AssignedTo` field:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Workflow Tasks')/items?$select=AssignedTo/Id,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo
```

---

Depending on whether field is multi-valued or not, the following formats are supported when setting `User/Lookup` field value via SharePoint REST API:

- single-valued user field: `'<fieldname>Id' : <user id>`
- multi-valued user field: `'<fieldname>Id' : { 'results': [<array of user ids>] }`

The following examples demonstrates how to set user field value using SharePoint 2013 REST API

**Multiple user field value**

The example demonstrates how to create a task item and specify *multi-valued* `AssignedTo` field:

```
//Create a Task item
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval',
    'AssignedToId' : { 'results': [10] }
};
createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',taskProperties)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('Task has been created successfully');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

**Single user field value**

The example demonstrates how to create a task item and specify a *single-valued* **AssignedTo** field:

```
//Create a Task item
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval',
    'AssignedToId' : 10
};
createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',taskProperties)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('Task has been created successfully');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function createListItem(webUrl,listName,itemProperties) 
{    
    return $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",   
       type: "POST",   
       processData: false,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
       headers: {   
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer!